# Invisible google captcha v2 is not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

The following code is working fine when the form is submitted correctly with all valid data in the first attempt. If there is any server side error after submitting the form then when user resubmits the form the recaptcha does not reset.
Following is the sample code:

**html-form**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<div>
<form name="signupForm"  method="POST" action="/signup">
    <div class="form-group mobile-number">
        <input type="tel" id="mobileNo" class="form-control" name="mobileNumber" maxlength="10"
               autofocus>

    <label for="mobile"> Your Mobile no. </label>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="{key}"
        data-callback="setResponse"
        data-badge="inline"
        data-size="invisible">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="captcha-response" name="captcha-response"/>
    <button id="submitButon" type="submit">Sign me up!</button>
</form>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function setResponse(response) {
        document.getElementById('captcha-response').value = response;
        submitForm();
    }

    function submitForm() {
        var $form = $("form");
        var data = JSON.stringify($form.serializeObject());
        var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(data);

        data = JSON.stringify(myJsonObject);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dummy url",
            contentType: "application/json",
            xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            data: data,
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                // success
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                // logics here
                grecaptcha.execute();
                setResponse;
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        //homepage form
        $('form[name="signupForm"]').validate({
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            },
            rules: {
                mobileNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 10
                }
            },
// Specify validation error messages
            messages: {
                mobileNumber: "A valid mobile number is of 10-digit",

            },
//submit handler
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                submitForm();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think the error is in ajax call but not able to figure out why the captcha is not resetting again.

Comment: have you tried `grecaptcha.reset()` ?

Comment: yes, in the error of ajax, I have tried with `grecaptcha.reset()`.

Comment: At a quick glance, document.ready fires before ajax events (but after everything else.) The google code refreshes by ajax, but your ready is setting up some of your page.

I suspect you need to check that you need to double-check your stuff in ready doesn't also need to be in an .ajaxComplete as well.